# No mapping for font in docx4j

Tags: java, fonts, docx4j

I tried to set font to docx file with docx4j library like this:

```
RFonts font = new RFonts();

font.setAscii("David");
font.setHAnsi("David");
font.setCs("David");
ParaRPr rpr = ppr.getRPr();
rpr.setRFonts(font);
```

and I got warning like this:

```
2018-09-13T14:24:35.847+0300  WARN [Thttp-nio-8080-exec-11] [] [org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.FontHandler:95] No mapping for: 'David'
```

I tried to add font to list in fonthandler class but no luck.

what can i do?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your RFonts code and the log WARN are unrelated.

As per the log message, it is coming from org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.FontHandler (ie during xhtml to docx conversion).

To map a font used in the XHTML to a docx font, do something like:

```
    // Setup font mapping
    RFonts rfonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
    rfonts.setAscii("Century Gothic");
    XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping("Century Gothic", rfonts);
```